C# For loop with try catch finally
I am trying to run for loop for every 5 secs to get the readings from COM port. When successful getting the readings only once. Would like to run the loop even if there is error. sometimes the readings will be available at 4th iteration.
Below is the code I am using. I am a newbie to development. Can someone please help me out?
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;


public class Program
{


    public static SerialPort? _serialPort;
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i<= 5; i++)

        Console.WriteLine(i);
        
             // Create a new SerialPort object
             _serialPort = new SerialPort();

            // Set the port name (COM1, COM2, etc.)
            _serialPort.PortName = "COM3";


            // Set baud rate
            _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;

            // Set parity (none, odd, even, mark, space)
            _serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;

            // Set data bits
            _serialPort.DataBits = 8;

                // Set stop bits (one, two, or more)
            _serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;

            // Set handshake (none, requestToSend, requestToSendXOnXOff, xOnXOff)
                _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

            // Set read/write timeouts
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
            Console.WriteLine("hello");

            {
                
                try
                {

                    // Open the serial port
                    _serialPort.Open();


                    Console.WriteLine("Totals list");
                    // Write data to the serial port
                    _serialPort.WriteLine("T");

                    // Read data from the serial port
                    response = _serialPort.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("    Totals list: " + response);

                    Console.WriteLine("Data list");
                    // Write data to the serial port
                    _serialPort.WriteLine("D");

                    // Read data from the serial port
                    response = _serialPort.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("    Data list: " + response);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                    
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        // Close the serial port
                        if (_serialPort.IsOpen) 
                        {
                            _serialPort.Close();
                            Console.WriteLine("Serial port closed.");
                            }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                    

        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}


Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint on your for loop and step through the code. It should become immediately clear what the problem is with the code you've posted. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is an excellent time to learn.

Please learn not to sprinkle your code with catch (Exception ex) blocks. They just end up swallowing errors and making it harder for you to actually write robust code. You should only ever catch specific exceptions that you can meaningfully handle.

Query the serial port's "BytesToRead" property, instead of reading blindly. Port reading is about expecting a certain length, based on the query and / or a response code and length (in a header). Your buffer should be at least as big as the biggest response you can expect; BytesToRead tells you what to do.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

Hello @KenWhite , Thanks for your response. I am getting this error when I try to use debugger. Not sure how to handle it . Can not find an opened workspace folder. Please open a folder before starting to debug with a 'dotnet' configuration'.

Looks like you forgot braces for your loop, it should be for (int i = 1; i<= 5; i++){< loop body >}

@JonasHL Ah, you destroyed a perfect teachable moment by giving it away. Now the OP won't have a chance to learn how the debugger works - you've deprived them of a chance to get started using the most powerful tool they'll ever have as a coder. Shame. :-(

@Diya: The debugger is the most powerful tool a coder has in their toolbox. The second one is the ability to learn to use your favorite search engine. https://www.google.com/search?q=Can+not+find+an+opened+workspace+folder.+Please+open+a+folder+before+starting+to+debug+with+a+%27dotnet%27+configuration

You should not loop in the Open/Close of Serial Port. Also open the port once and try reading the values.
DataReceived  event will be called when serial port has any data do check.
For additional checks, you can also use [there seems to be text missing here. -Peter]
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text;
        
class Program
{
    public static SerialPort _serialPort;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");
        _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
        _serialPort.DataReceived += _serialPort_DataReceived;

        try
        {
            _serialPort.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle open exception
        }
    }


    private static void _serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[_serialPort.BytesToRead];
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Length];

        if (bytes.Length > 0)
        {

            _serialPort.Read(bytes, 0, buffer.Length);
            string myData = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
        }
    }
}


There seems to be part of your suggestions missing where I inserted my commentary.

By the way, I think the OP is writing something to the port and then expecting a response; that may be better modeled with the synchronous approach in their own code (which, I suppose with zero domain knowledge, is also a valid way to control the port).
